# ORM и префиксы у таблиц

Tags: entity-framework, orm

Задача следующая, при регистрации клиента надо в базе создавать набор таблиц с уникальным префиксом, это вообще возможно реализовать используя EF?

Comment: Что значит с уникальным? На каждую таблицу разный или на все общий но для конкретного приложения один?

Comment: А причём тут ASP.net?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в контекст работы с базой на каждую модель:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourModel>().ToTable(prefix+"tableName", "dbo");
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, это возможно.

Вам потребуется описать структуру ваших таблиц в виде entities — насколько я понял, она для разных пользователей будет идентична?

Затем, с помощью fluent API надо будет привязать entities и таблицы — фактически, указать, что вот этот вот класс будут отображаться на таблицу с таким-то именем.

**Конкретика**

Предположим, вы хотите создавать для каждого пользователя одну таблицу такого вида:

```
public UserValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Нам потребуется наследник `DbContext` в котором описаны нужные таблицы с заданным префиксом:

```
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<UserValue> UserValues { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext(string prefix)
        : base(PrepareCompiledModel(prefix))
    { }

    private static DbCompiledModel PrepareCompiledModel(string prefix)
    {
        var builder = new DbModelBuilder();
        builder.Entity<UserValue>.ToTable(prefix + "UserValue");

        return builder.Compile();
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что построение модели — задача ресурсоёмкая. Сам EF умеет кешировать построенные и скомпилированные модели, но в вашем случае *очень динамической модели БД* придётся озаботиться этим самостоятельно.

В простом случае вы можете завести статический словарь (`static IDictionary<string, DbCompiledModel>`) внутри класса `MyDbContext` и проверять в методе `PrepareCompiledModel`, нет ли уже модели с таким префиксом.

**Использование**

У вас будет основной (статический) контекст БД, в котором фиксированы имена таблиц. Оттуда вы прочитаете префикс для каждого конкретного пользователя.

```
var staticContext = new StaticDbContext();
var prefix = staticContext.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id).Prefix;

var dynamicContext = new MyDbContext(prefix);
var foos = dynamicContext.UserValues.Where(uv => uv.Value == "foo");
```